# Getting the source code for the following page using Java

Tags: java, url, gzip

I am trying to get the source code for the following page: http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/082470732X/ref=dp_olp_0?ie=UTF8&redirect=true&condition=all
(Please note that Amazon takes you to another page if you click on the link. To get to the page that I am interested in reading please copy the link and paste it to an empty tab in your browser. Thanks!)

Normally using java.net API, I can get the source code for most of the URLs with almost no problem, however for the above link I get nothing. It turned out that the input stream generated by the connection is encoded by gzip, so I tried the following:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
String encoding = urlConnection.getContentEncoding();
if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
     is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
} else if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("deflate")) {
     is = new InflaterInputStream((is), new Inflater(true));
}
```

However this time I get the following error deterministically:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:249)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:239)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:142)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:58)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:67)
at domain.logic.ItemScraper.loadURL(ItemScraper.java:405)
at domain.logic.ItemScraper.main(ItemScraper.java:510)
```

Can anybody see my mistake? Is there another way to read this particular page? Can somebody explain me why my browser (firefox) can read it, however I cannot read the source using Java?

Thanks in advance, best regards,

Comment: i can view it with the VIEW GENERATED SOURCE in Firefox with the WebDeveloper plugin.  Seems silly to do this with Java to be honest

Comment: where is `is` set up? .. the one passed into GZIPInputStream

Comment: Please post where you create `is`.

Comment: Sorry all, is was already like: is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
```

try

```
is = new GZIPInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

As for the `EOFException`, if you add

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24");
```

it would go away.

Comment: Excellent answer. It worked! Could you explain, what this does? I mean what changed? Did it tricked Amazon to be like a real web browser or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard BufferedReader to read the response of a webserver of a given URL.

```
URLIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(URLOrFilename).openStream()));
```

Then use ...

```
while ((incomingLine = URLIn.readLine()) != null) {
 ...
}
```

... to get the response.

Comment: Ah, you're right - that was a typo (I've corrected the code). I used the above code in a web spider I wrote years ago in Java 1.4.2 - so it should work in any version newer than that.